# Is it possable to manulaly log tor with journalctl

Tags: configuration, log

I am trying to log tor with the following command:

```
journalctl -f -u tor@default.service | echo < log.tor.txt
```

Is there anything that I should change?
Is this possible with journalctl? should I see something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like redirecting the output of `journalctl` is a bit tricky, see [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170469/how-to-direct-the-journal-output-of-certain-units-to-a-particular-file) for more context

You may want to use

```
sudo journalctl > complete.log.txt
```

Depending on your needs you can use `journalctl -f` instead

Then you can filter the results with

```
cat complete.log.txt | grep tor
```

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/360793/440770

Comment: The file will remain blank.  The logs that will normally show up do not show up.  In turn, nothing will happen.  BTW, that command will not work.  I tried restarting tor, and the file still showed me nothing.

Comment: It seems like redirecting the output of `journalctl` is a bit tricky, I updated my answer

Comment: SystemD - a journalctl is a part of it's suite - has a great API for accessing and doing logs, so your task can be solved even without a file redirection! Keep in mind that the size and the depth of journals are configurable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best and the right way is to use Tor as a SystemD service - **don't forget to build it by hand with this features enabled**! It's totally not the problem - SystemD offers a service groups nowdays and you can use them to tailor all your specific needs without discarding runtime dependencies and starting/stopping grouping and order.